# Mysql Between Clause inside Case when statement and count number of items in column

Tags: mysql, count, case

Here i am trying to get the count of products by using case when in mysql . 
My sample data is

```
 ID | Proname | led | lcd | hd | fullhd | 3d | displaysize (inches) |  brandID
 1    tv1        1     0     0     1       0      22                      3
 2    tv2        0     1     1     0       0      26                      3 
 3    tv3        1     0     1     0       0      32                      3
 4    tv4        1     0     0     1       1      55                      3  
 5    tv5        1     0     0     1       0      42                      3
```

Now my expected out put

```
lcdcnt | ledcnt | hdcnt | fullhdcnt | 3dcnt | dispcntlessthan32 | displaycntbetwwen32and42 | displaycntabove42
  1        4       2         3          1
```

Here is my Query . but i am not getting the correct output as i expected

```
select 
    sum(lcdtv) lcdcnt,
    sum(ledtv) ledcnt,
    sum(3dtv) 3dcnt,
    sum(plasmatv) plasmacnt,
    sum(smarttv) smatcnt,
    sum(hdtv) hdnt,
    sum(fullhdtv) fullhdcnt,
    sum(ultrahdtv) ultrahdcnt,
    sum(4ktv) 4kcnt,
    sum(8ktv) 8kcnt,
    sum(oledtv) oledcnt,
    case
        when (displayinches between 1 and 32) then count(displayinches)
    end as dispcntlessthan32
case
        when (displayinches between 32 and 42) then count(displayinches)
    end as displaycntbetwwen32and42
from
    tv
where
    brandID = 3 and (ledtv = 1) and price != 0
```

Comment: So try to write the query from the scratch, step by step. The scenario like "I've written a messy query and looking for someone to fix it" isn't the most efficient one.

Comment: Yeap. Not to mention that there are references to columns not in the table such as `displayinches`...

Comment: just i have given the example of the query i tried. i am expecting the output like that.

Comment: I think no one understands my question and what i expected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Here is the SQLFiddel Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1bc40/40)**

**Below is the Approach :**

```
select 
    sum(lcd) lcdcnt,
    sum(led) ledcnt,
    sum(3d) 3dcnt,
    sum(hd) hdnt,
    sum(fullhd) fullhdcnt,
    sum(3d) 3dcnt,
    sum(case when displaysize between 1  and 32 then 1 else 0 end) as dispcntlessthan32,
    sum(case when displaysize between 33 and 42 then 1 else 0 end) as displaycntbetween32and42
from table1
where brandID = 3
```

Comment: here the dispcntlessthan32 is 1 according to the query . but the count to be 3